# Taskbar/Desktop icon flashing on launch, but not opening

Tags: windows-7, browser, taskbar, desktop-icons, flashing

My computer is a normal Windows 7 - Ultimate box, 64-bit version. Nothing too fancy, but not too shabby either.

I use it for browsing the net and a daily portion (of healthy!) gaming.
Nothing more, nothing less...

Lately my internet browsers started acting up, mainly Chrome & Firefox.
I don't seem to have the issue with Internet Explorer though.

Every now and then, I open a new session and when clicking my shortcut on desktop or task-bar... nothing happens!
The icon will light up on my task-bar, as its opened and then just disappears again. Without opening any window or displaying an error message.

The work-around is to keep clicking it until it eventually opens.
Most of the time it takes about 4-5 tries and then it's working like nothing ever happened!

I don't know what I'm supposed to do here, I tried to unpin and pin the new session. A fresh re-install doesn't work either, I'm at the end of the road here. And it's pretty annoying that it's random, sometimes it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! It seems it was a malware .dll file called Sprotts.